# How do I cancel other onclick function calls further down the call chain?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, onclick, dom-events

I have an element with this `onclick` attribute:

```
onclick="ieDisabledBtn(); widgetPayTotalDue.show();"
```

I've added the first function, if appropriate, I do **not** want to execute the 2nd function.  I basically need to tweak some things for IE (fake a disabled button by making it read-only, but not make it clickable).  I can not use a disabled button as IE renders gray text for disabled button text.  I can not use a disabled button.

Here is where I'm setting up my fake disabled button for IE:

```
    (function() {
    var $disabled_btns = $('button[disabled]');
    
    if ($disabled_btns && $.browser.msie) {
        $disabled_btns.each(function() {
            $(this)
                .removeAttr('disabled')
                .attr({
                    'readonly': 'readonly',
                    'disabledIE': true //set a flag, used in ieDisabledBtn()
                })
                .click(function() {
                    $(this)
                        .removeClass('ui-state-focus') //don't want this button style
                        .find('span').css({ //need to shift text so it stays in same position
                            'position': 'relative',
                            'top': '-1px;',
                            'left': '1px;'
                    });
                    
                    return false;
                }); //end click
        }); //end each
    } //end if
})();
```

Here is my `ieDisabledBtn` function:

```
function ieDisabledBtn(e) {
    //we only care about IE
    if ($.browser.msie){
        var e       = window.event,
            btn     = e.srcElement;
        
        //yes, we're a disabled IE btn, stop any other onclick events bound to this btn from firing
        if (btn.getAttribute('disabledIE')) { 
            e.returnValue   = false;
            e.cancelBubble  = true;
            
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I  thought for sure it'd just be a matter of setting `e.returnValue = false` and I've gone around several variations but I'm still getting that second function executed.

What am I missing?

I'm going to have these buttons spread throughout this app and they call different framework modals so I'm wanting to be able to just prefix those `onclick`s with a new function which will stop further `onclick` functions from executing if appropriate.

Comment: You're missing that you don't return anything in the onclick attribute code, so code execution continues normally.

Comment: That's not it.  I had that in there earlier and it wasn't working.  Added it back and it's still not working.  Code above is revised with that inclusion.

Comment: If I drop in some more alerts, the order of execution on the button click is: 1) ieDisabledBtn() which returns false 2) jQuery click handler which returns false 3) widgetPayTotalDue.show()

Comment: Looks like I got it with adding e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: Thought stopImmediatePropagation() did it, but that isn't available in IE8.  It looked like it was working for me but it was throwing a JS error, hence stopping further execution of code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two statements in your onclick event handler (`ieDisabledBtn(); widgetPayTotalDue.show();`) they will both be called.  The onclick attribute roughly translates to:

```
function()
{
  ieDisabledBtn();
  widgetPayTotalDue.show();
}
```

So you need `ieDisabledBtn()` to return `true` when you want `widgetPayTotalDue.show()` to be called, which means:

```
function()
{
  if(ieDisabledBtn())
  {
    widgetPayTotalDue.show();
  }
}
```

or:

`onclick="if(ieDisabledBtn()) widgetPayTotalDue.show()"`

It's better to only have a single function to be bound to an event, for simplicity, if you can help it.  Then you can make that function do whatever you like and keep it readable.